Common term for lib.exe and ar commands
I wanted to ask this question on meta but it appears it's more appropriate to ask here:
Microsoft's lib.exe is used to create static libraries.
Under Linux the ar program is used for same.
What's the proper term for both of these?
For instance when we say g++ or msvc proper and common term is compiler, likewise for link.exe and ld common proper term is linker
But what about lib.exe and ar? what's the proper term for these like for "compiler" and "linker" cases above?
